# Crear objeto dinámico

Tags: javascript, algoritmos, vuejs

Tengo un array:

```
funciones = ['paciente.hospital', 'paciente.enfermad', 'paciente.documento'];
```

y una cadena:

```
const parametro = '72476675';
```

Lo que quiero lograr hacer es crear un objeto dinamico a partir de este array y esta cadena de tal forma que quede:

```
const result = {
   exp: 'paciente.hospitap',
   params: {
     exp: 'paciente.enfermedad',
     params: {
        exp: 'paciente.documento',
        params: parametro,
     }
   },
};
```

donde el ultimo elemento de funciones recibirá el parámetro que es la cadena.

```
const result = {};
funciones.forEach((fn, i) => {
  if (i === funciones.length - 1) { // si es el ultimo le asignamos el parametro
     result.exp = parametro
  } else {
     // aqui no se como ir acumulando el objeto
     console.log(fn);
  }
});
```

El problema es que no se como ir acumulando el objeto ya que este arreglo de funciones puede tener menos o mas elementos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilizando [`array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce) podrías obtener dicho resultado.

Al iterar el arreglo:
- Creamos las propiedades `exp` y `params` para el objeto `acc`.
- Si es el último valor en lugar de asignar un `{}` a `params`, asignamos `parámetro`.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
const funciones = ['paciente.hospital', 'paciente.enfermad', 'paciente.documento'];
const parametro = '72476675';
const result = {};

funciones.reduce((acc, func, idx, arr) => {
  acc.exp = func;
  acc.params = (idx + 1 == arr.length) ? parametro : {};
  return acc.params;
}, result);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

Usando `.reduceRigth` se podría solucionar:

```js
const funciones = ['paciente.hospital', 'paciente.enfermad', 'paciente.documento'];


const parametro = '72476675';

const res = funciones.reduceRight((p, c) => {
    let t = ("params" in p)?{ ...p }:parametro;
    p.exp = c;
    p.params = t;
    return p;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```

La idea sería iterar desde la derecha, y agregar el objeto actual dentro de un nuevo objeto, el caso distínto sería la primera vez, an donde agregamos  `parametro`.